# Unable to set log level in logbook so that it doesn't log other levels

Tags: python, logging, logbook

I am using [Logbook](http://logbook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for logging. When I set the level for a log for example `WARNING` it also logs `ERROR`level logs. How can I just set the logging level to `WARNING`.

```
from logbook import StreamHandler, ERROR, WARNING, CRITICAL, INFO, Logger
import sys

handler = StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.push_application()
log = Logger('demo', WARNING)
log.info("Knock Knock")
# no output
log.error("Knock Knock")
# output : [2017-08-17 09:59:49.133053] ERROR: demo: Knock Knock
log.warning("Knock Knock")
# output : [2017-08-17 09:59:49.133053] WARNING: demo: Knock Knock
```

I don't want `log.error` to output anything. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Error`is going to be show because it has bigger priority than `Warning`. When you set the level to `Warning` it implies that it is `Warning` or above.
For example, when you set the level to `Info` it will display `Info`, `Warning` and `Errors`.

Comment: How can I set it to equal to?

Comment: That's not the intended behavior of loggers. More specifically for your question, when you see the signature of the StreamHandler `logbook.StreamHandler(self, stream, level=0, format_string=None, encoding=None, filter=None, bubble=False)` it appears to be no option to select only one of the levels (I might be mistaken).